# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've command on my bot, but the issue it works fine for some hours, but suddenly it throws an error.

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {

    if (!args[0].includes("https://www.roblox.com/games/")) return message.reply("Invalid Format!"); 

    // ^ Where it throws an error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

    const { pathname } = new URL(args[0]);
    if (!pathname) return message.channel.send("Invalid URL Provided");
    let id = pathname.slice(pathname.indexOf("s/") + 2, pathname.lastIndexOf("/"));

}
```

Comment: Can't really help much without further context, but the reason the error comes is because `args[0]` is undefined. So you might wanna check why the args is empty (assuming it is supposed to be array in the first place).

Comment: Do a null safe check

Comment: let argsZero = args?.[0] ?? null; //now you check if argZero is null you can check it using if and throw an error before condition

Comment: if(argsZero===null) return message.reply("invalid format");

Comment: seems to be nothing wrong with the code you showed here, but the args may be returned ``undefined`` . that's why there is a type of error.

Comment: Thanks to @ucup, I have resolved my issue appreciate it!